# How to use the "Remote Systems" view in Eclipse to explore a Docker container file system?

Tags: eclipse, docker, remote-access, boot2docker

The Eclipse `Remote Systems` view is a great tool to connect to VMs and explore their file systems, currently the following options are available:

[image]

First I find out the container IP by running this command:

```
docker inspect <container> | grep IPAddress | cut -d '"' -f 4
```

Once I have the IP, I launch the `New Connection` wizard from the `Remote Systems` view, I tried to select `Linux`, `SSH only` and `FTP only` and in the `Hostname` field I paste the container IP, click Finish and the connection seems to be successfully created, now when I try to expand the the `Files` node it prompts for User and Password, the problem is that I don't have that info, does the user/pass vary from container to container? how can I get this info?

Comment: Do you have a reproducer? The docker image you are using? THe commands used to start this container?

Comment: I'm using the official `node` image, the command I used to download it was `docker run -d -p 80:9080 -p 443:9443 node`

Answer (score 1):

You can just instantiate a container with that image but with a shell so that you can see what usernames are configured on that image.

```
docker run -it node /bin/bash
```

You can then configure users, password and do a:

```
docker commit <image-name> my-node:0.1
```

Then you can instantiate a new container:

```
docker run -d -p 80:9080 -p 443:9443 my-node
```

Is `ssh` also running in that container? If not you will have to install it into the container so that you can ssh to it.

Answer (score 1):

A docker container only runs a single parent process at a time (on your host machine that parent process is 'init' which runs a bunch of system services).  In the case of your node container, that parent process is a node server.

Eclipse connects to a remote machine by connecting to a listener on that machine using some protocol.  SSH of FTP, for example.  With the docker container, there is no process listening for this connection, so you cannot connect using Eclipse as it is.  You have two options...

1. Use the command line and `docker exec` to connect to the machine and explore its filesystem.  No pretty pictures, but you don't need a lot of knowledge.
2. Modify your container in some way to connect to it.  you have two options here...

A.  Modify your image to run an SSH daemon.  A simple way to do that is to use the phusion/baseimage container as your parent, and have it spawn both the ssh daemon and the node server.  You need to know a good amount about linux sysadmin to get this working (not a lot, but a good amount).

B.  Launch a second copy of the container with a different command, such as ssh -d.  You can then connect to the second copy.  This has the downside that it won't be the same container you're interested in, and you STILL have to modify the image since I doubt the node image even has an ssh daemon installed... but it is less knowledge than wrapping your head around runit.

Comment: Thanks Paul, about this "You can then connect to the second copy", how can I do that?

Comment: If you have the ssh daemon running in the second copy, you would have to 1. Figure out the IP address of that copy, and 2. set eclipse to connect to that hostname.